# Questions about Using Monte Carlo simulation to determine the control limits of control chart

Tags: monte-carlo, quality-control

[image]

The Montacaro simulation method is used to solve the control limit of the control chart, how to determine the randomly generated data streams, and whether it needs to be generated according to the observed historical data; Further, why did you choose 5000 points, and are any other values of any size acceptable.

When I read this paper, I thought that one million streams containing 5000 points were randomly generated according to N(0,1), which had nothing to do with the monitored historical data. Maybe my idea was wrong, because in this case, the control limit of all systems was the same. But the original paper did not tell me in detail how random data should relate to sample data.

Original paper link:https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/TECH.2011.10069
,https://sci-hub.se/10.1198/TECH.2011.10069

Comment: Most of your questions appear to be answered in the text included in the image.  The reason for 5000 points is unclear but might be related to previous material not shown.